# How to load config spec from a file using setcs command in rcleartool from cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cleartool

I am trying to create a web view, load the config spec and pull the objects into the view, in my local system using rcleartool.
I am getting an error when trying to load the config spec from a file using the setcs command

The commands I am using are

```
cmd> echo ServerURL | rcleartool mkview -tag Temp_View Temp_View
cmd> copy Temp_View.txt Temp_View
cmd> cd Temp_View
cmd> echo ServerURL | rcleartool setcs -ove Temp_View.txt
```

The error I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri 'ServerURL /cltxt/9c6f8f42621e43f8b4a6d10027aed9e2/ac39de36ffdf4a4fb38ffed40f9bc33e/unix': escaped absolute path not valid
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.<init>(HttpMethodBase.java:219)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod.<init>(GetMethod.java:88)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.rpc.GetRequestGenerator.<init>(GetRequestGenerator.java:44)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.rpc.Session.createRequestGenerator(Session.java:255)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.rpc.AbstractRpc.sendRequest(AbstractRpc.java:672)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.rpc.AbstractRpc.requestHelper(AbstractRpc.java:340)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.rpc.AbstractRpc.sendGet(AbstractRpc.java:432)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.copyarea.GetClearText$GetCltxtRpc.sendAndProcessGetRequest(GetClearText.java:281)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.copyarea.GetClearText.fetchClearTextViaGET(GetClearText.java:193)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.copyarea.GetClearText.run(GetClearText.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

However, the same works fine when I open a cleartool session and then follow the same steps

```
cmd> rcleartool
rcleartool> mkview -tag Temp_View Temp_View
rcleartool> exit
cmd> copy Temp_View.txt Temp_View
cmd> cd Temp_View
cmd> rcleartool
rcleartool> setcs -ove Temp_View.txt
```

How can I avoid the "escaped absolute path not valid" error, since I cannot remove the white space in the uri the rcleartool generated?